# What is an incremental file & full file concept?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

SSIS - Source file came as like incremental file & full file but need full concept about those why call full & incremental file?

Answer (score 0):

Full file will usually mean that file contains all data, so data received on previous day should be discarded and replaced. Typical example can be list of products.
Incremental file will contain only difference or new data from last transmission. Typical example is file with yesterday transactions. To get all transactions you will need to combine data from all received files.

Comment: The basic concept increment file mean those source file which is content new & updated record only and full file mean those source file which is content old, update and new record also